Filesystem and module in node js
Can someone please help with this?

import the fs module
create and export a module with a function readAndWrite with following functionality
should read the content of input.txt and write it to duplicate.txt using filesystem functions
Note: specify the encoding string utf8 while reading the file
console log the message "Content copied to duplicate.txt"

Code:
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => 
    {
        if (err) throw err;
            fs.writeFileSync('duplicate.txt', data, (err) => 
                {
                    if (err) throw err;
                        console.log('Content copied to duplicate.txt');
                })
    }


readFileSync doesn't take a callback. Its a synchronous function. If you want it to be async, use readFile  from node:fs/promises module.

Sounds like a homework.

You seem to have the right idea, but the sync variants of these functions don't take callabcks. Also, you're missing the export of this function:
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    readAndWrite() {
        fs.writeFileSync
            ('duplicate.txt', fs.readFileSync('input.txt', {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
        console.log('Content copied to duplicate.txt');
    } 
};

